# Python regex search for decimal digits not followed by character

Tags: python, regex

Using re.search to find one or more decimal digits, an optional K character, not followed by a '%'.

Tried this:

```
re.search (r'(\d+K?)(?!%)', s).group (0)
```

With the following values for s:

```
10K 1%
2% 10K
20% 10K
```

Which returns:

```
10K
10K
2
```

The first two results are correct, the last one is not.  I want the digit matching to be greedy and skip the "20%" and match the "10K" instead.  Found a solution for Java (++), but not Python.  Thanks for any tips on this, searched online extensively, but answer has been elusive.

Comment: Are word boundaries significant? `\b(\d+K?)(?!%)\b` may help.

Comment: @ggorlen no, they aren't unfortunately.  It could be a standalone value like 10K or just a number like 100.  I'm trying to parse a resistor value from schematics which could be just a resistance value, but could also have a percent tolerance, in either order and possibly with no space in between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try regex `\d+K?(?= |$)`

This will check a space or an End of the line after K.

[Regex](https://regex101.com/r/c3SFT9/1)

Comment: Looks like this one works fairly well for my purposes.  I didn't think to use a positive look ahead instead of a negative.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`?` mean match 0 or 1 time, replace pattern to `(\d+K)(?!%)`

Comment: 'K' is optional though.  Guess I should have made that clear in the examples.